# Beautiful Soup (Python) : find all kind of div, p, span, etc, with a given class

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-requests

Given a specific URL rendered with Python/requests, I need to findAll kind of div, h3, p, etc with class name "Specific".

This works partially :

```
data = soup.findAll("div", { "class" : "Specific" })
```

because it only finds div.

I am looking for something like :

```
data = soup.findAll("*", { "class" : "Specific" })
```

**Good answer from soon** :

```
data = soup.find_all(class_='Specific')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify [`class_`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class) parameter in the `find_all` method. `name` parameter may be omitted as well:

```
In [12]: html = '''<div class='Specific'><span class='Specific c1'></span><p class='NonSpecific'></p></div>'''

In [13]: soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

In [14]: soup.find_all(class_='Specific')
Out[14]: 
[<div class="Specific"><span class="Specific c1"></span><p class="NonSpecific"></p></div>,
 <span class="Specific c1"></span>]
```